# How can I do Android studio plugin automation?

Tags: java, android-studio, selenium-webdriver, automation, winappdriver

I'm trying to automate a plugin in Android studio. An android studio plugin added to the menu section above. I want to run it on all platforms (Windows, Mac and Ubuntu).

I used WinAppDriver (Selenium-Java) and inspect.exe but without success. Because I can't display AutomationID in inspect.exe for android studio. If you have a different solution, I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I tried to solve the problems by doing different experiments, but unfortunately I can't. As far as I understand it is something related to Android Studio's permissions. How can I solve this problem?